# how to get image from server and display on page?

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have meet all pages and did implement, but did not get result what i am looking for. Here is the database picture at this link : "http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1389533907",  that i want to get and display. I have upload code. Now i am trying to display. That is the code which from this forum: "p" is the name of myfolder.

```
<?php
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
 mysql_select_db("project",$con) or die("error db");

$sql="select * from upload";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$image=$row ['name'];

echo '<img src=\"p/'.$image.'" width="360" height="150">';
}

?>
```

Comment: what you see in HTML view source in browser ?

Comment: What's the question? Do you have an image in a mysql database you would like to display in the users browser?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I believe the name column contains the name of the image e.g. "img1.png" but he has stored the image in a blob

Comment: Yeah people usually do not do basic debug like checking the source or echoing the data and these debugs solve most of the issues to see whats wrong :)

Comment: it does show very tiny something like clip art picture a very small one. Not the exact picture which i ve place in server.

Comment: I think you store only the name of the image file in database.
Am I Right?

Comment: echo "<img src='"p/".$image.' width='360' height='150'>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display an image stored as a blob you need to read it from the database then either include it in the users browser as a data uri or print the binary data along with the appropriate headers.

DataURL:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['content'] ) . '" />';
```

Or where $size is from `length(content)` in the SQL query:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myimage.png");

print $row['content'];
```

Comment: thanks man. But would u lik to tell me whats blob and whats the simple alternative for this??

Comment: alternative means what should i do if i want to use top suggestion listed by the people.

Comment: BLOB means Binary Large Objects and it is used in such situations where large sized data is to be stored...
But using this may increase your cost of storage..
So as an alternative,you could provide only the filenames in databases and storing the original files on server itself..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
 echo ("<img src='path/$image width='360' height='150' />");
```

Comment: what is path is that C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\p??? that is the think i did but i just get small box

Comment: If your images are in folder named "p" then echo ("<img src='p/$image width='360' height='150' />"); path means folder name which contains images.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_* is deprecated, use msqli_***

```
$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "project") or die('Connection error');

$result = mysqli_query($cn, "SELECT * FROM upload") or die( mysqli_error($cn) );

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{
    printf('<img src="p/%s" width="360" height="150">', urlencode($row['name']));
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($cn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<img src=\"/p/$image\" width=\"360\" height=\"150\">";
```